# WebPart to dynamically display links to all views within a list or library

Tags: web-part, css

I'm trying to develop a WebPart that I can place on the top of a SharePoint 2010 list or library page that will dynamically display links to the views created within the library. I want to also format the links to look like a clean CSS menu. I am able to do this manually by adding the links and some CSS code into a Content Editor WebPart, but it is too much work to manually do this for all the lists and libraries we currently have. Also If a view is ever added or removed I have to update the CEWP manually.

No matter how many times I explain to my users that there is a drop down in the ribbon for all the list views, they still forget and my boss would like something that is more visually striking.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to get this accomplished.

Thanks in advance.